# Does a rotating black hole change a left-handed neutrino into a right-handed neutrino?

Tags: general-relativity, dirac-equation, neutrinos

The Dirac equation in a gravitational field contains a torsion term $\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\omega^{nm}_\mu \sigma_{nm}\psi$. In the Weyl represnetation the spinor $\psi$ can be written as $\psi=(\psi_L, \psi_R)$.

For massless particles such as neutrinos, the Dirac equation separates into separate equations for left and right handed particles.

In a rotating gravitational source this torsion term containing the spin-connection $\omega$ is non-zero and appears to mix $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$. This would be fine for an electron but for a neutrino which is only known to come in one handed-ness, this seems problematic.

Thus is it true that a left-handed neutrino near a rotating black hole can change into a right-handed neutrino? This seems wrong. What is the mistake here?

Edit: I forgot people now think neutrinos have a small mass. So I suppose this isn't so bad. But is it true?

Comment: The thing is you can have a right handed neutrino, such a neutrino is sterile and only interacts gravitationally

Comment: @Triatticus but wouldn't this mean a beam of left-handed neutrinos going passed a star for example, would seem to dissapear?

Comment: It's possible the rate for a typical star is extremely small as the curvature is very small.